# How to scroll in android LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i have an application, where i want to use scroll option in liner layout. Please help me i am stuck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    >

    <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/clock1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/rssbtn" android:src="@drawable/rss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/widget1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/widget2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Plain" android:checked="false" android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/widget3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Serif" android:checked="true" android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0" android:typeface="serif">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/widget25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bold" android:checked="false" android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:textStyle="bold">
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>


    <Spinner android:id="@+id/widget1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />


    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/widget3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/plain_cb" android:text="Plain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/serif_cb" android:text="Serif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="serif" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/bold_cb" android:text="Bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/italic_cb" android:text="Italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:typeface="serif" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <DatePicker android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext1" android:text="EditText 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="(206)555-1212"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="serif" android:phoneNumber="true" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:text="SuperSecret"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:password="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not to wrap it with `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your LinearLayout in a ScrollView at the top of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
>
.....
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Neel,  if someone answers your question, please upvote their answer and mark it as correct ;)